# How to format a iCalender file by Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-outlook

I need to import the iCalender file to Task under Outlook. before I import that I need to modify the format by Excel.

[Original file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mX0E.png) looks like this.

I tried to use the build-in function Text-to-column, it doesn't work, also, I use a formula to added a comma ending with each line, and use Text to column again, still did not work.

I'm not good with Excel, but I guess If I can change the format like [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhBe5.png), Outlook will happy to import it. Sounds like group the each items(BEGIN,SUMMARY...)

Any idea I can format it by easy way or import to outlook?

Answer (score 0):

If possible, please tell me why do you need to modify the.ics file format. As far as I know, the .ics file can be imported in Outlook client. For specific steps, please refer to: [import-calendars-into-outlook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-calendars-into-outlook-8e8364e1-400e-4c0f-a573-fe76b5a2d379#:%7E:text=In%20Outlook%2C%20choose%20File%2C%20choose%20Open%20%26%20Export%2C,extracted%20file%20from%20your%20PC%20and%20choose%20OK.).

If you want to be able to import this file directly into the task folder in the outlook calendar, based on my experience and test, there seems to be no way to achieve it directly. As a workaround, It is recommended that you could try to open the .ics file in outlook(File>Open&Export>Open Calendar) and copy it to the task folder(Open the .ics file>File>Move to Folder>Copy to Folder>choose Task folder>Ok>Save and Close).

Comment: Thank you reply, the reason I need to do that is we want to transfer a Mail build-in task into Task in Outlook.


After I edited the iCalender file(open by Excel), I can import it into Outlook, but manually is so slow.


And the date in the original file looks like 202103261213.... rather than 26/03/2021....

Comment: I noticed that you are mainly concerned about how to use Excel to modify the .ics file format before importing the file into Outlook. Sorry that I know little about excel and only know about issues related to Outlook client.